# How do you create headers for c++ within the sublime text 2 interface?

Tags: c++, linux, header, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime text 2 to create a c++ program, but i do not know how to create and implement a new header in the interface. 
Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: Hi, you want to know how to create a new file in Sublime Text 2?  Or you don't know header files work?  Its not that clear.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, it is important to realize that Sublime Text 2 is a text editor, not an integrated development environment. Sublime Text has syntax highlighting features, essentially making it a "smart" text editor. Atop of this, there are several plugins which enable the user to get common features of typical IDEs, such as text completion. 
So, to answer your question, create a new file with an extension of `.h` and add appropriate header gaurds to it, and include it in your build system, whether it be `c-make` or `make` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

A header file is really no different to any other C++ file. By convention, they end in `.h` (or `.hpp`) and are only `#include`d by other C++ files. So all you need to do is simply create a new file (`File > New File` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and then save it (`File > Save` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) with a file name ending in `.h`.